# Msg 7105, Level 22, State 9 in delete query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete

I tried to execute this SQL query.

```
USE [Database]
GO

DELETE FROM [RMS].[Entities]
  WHERE [id] = 77
GO
```

And I got this error:

> Msg 7105, Level 22, State 9, Line 10 The Database ID 17, Page
>   (1:136088), slot 1 for LOB data type node does not exist. This is
>   usually caused by transactions that can read uncommitted data on a
>   data page. Run DBCC CHECKTABLE.

I tried DBCC CHECKDB and got 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors.
I tried also this code and got the same error.

```
USE [Database]
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED 
GO 

BEGIN TRANSACTION;  
GO

DELETE FROM [RMS].[Entities]
  WHERE [id] = 77
GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION;  
GO
```

Comment: It's rare but not unheard of for `DBCC CHECKDB` to miss actual errors. See if a `ALTER TABLE REBUILD` fixes things, or produces another error (warning: this could take a very long time and eat a lot of disk space if the table in question is large). Also worth trying is restoring a backup on a different machine and doing this again, to exclude the possibility of transient hardware failure (and to verify your backups are actually in order).

Comment: I tried ALTER TABLE REBUILD and I get the same error. Also restoring the database on another machine with again ALTER TABLE REBUILD didn't help.

Comment: Then I'd say you have a good case for opening up a ticket with Microsoft Support, as you appear to have persistent database corruption that `CHECKDB` can't detect or fix.

Comment: I will try that too. Thanks for your support.